# Digital Ocean server memory usage above 50%

Tags: memory, memory-management, flask, digital-ocean

I am deploying a Flask-based website on the server of Digital Ocean. And the website deployed is mainly static pages, config files and jsons.

**This morning I found the memory usage has exceeded 51%. Here is the snapshot.**

[image]

My memory is 512MB. Would someone please instruct me how to lower the memory usage? Thanks so much!

Update: I've use the "top" command in shell as suggested. Here is the snapshot, does it mean that it is the server itself eaten up those memories?

[image]

Comment: Questions about servers and infrastructure administration are off topic for Stack Overflow. You may get help on Server Fault.

Comment: Hi Charlotte, thanks for your suggestion

Comment: 50% of memory sounds very healthy. Are you running into any performance problems?

Comment: Hi halfer, thanks for your suggestion. I've enquired the client service team of Digital Ocean, and they said 50% is truly healthy as you mentioned. They suggested that if necessary, I can elevate the memory size of my server.

Answer (score 3):

The memory issue is not related to my application.

I just received the answer from Digital Ocean. Here it is:

> Hi there!
>
> Thank you for contacting us! We can help with any memory issues you're having!
>
> Since the Droplet is set up with only 512MB of RAM, once the system and any installed services start, it doesn't take much to push it past 50%. As a result, I don't think what you're seeing is necessarily abnormal under the circumstances. This leaves a few options: the Droplet can be resized and made larger to provide more memory (see https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-resize-your-droplets-on-digitalocean), you can add swap space to use part of the Droplet's file system as RAM (see https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-add-swap-on-ubuntu-14-04), or you can review the applications and services running on the Droplet and attempt to optimize them to reduce memory use.
>
> We hope this is helpful! Please let us know if there is anything else we can do!
>
> Regards,

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming your are running a Linux server. If so, you can use the `top` command.  It shows you all of the running processes and the system resources they are using. You would then be able to optimize from there.

Comment: Hi blazerunner44, I posted the snapshot of top command. Does it mean that it is the system itself eaten up the memory?

Comment: After running `top`, you can type `M` to sort processes by how much RAM they are using.

Answer (score 0):

I found out the cause! Linux borrows unused memory for disk caching. This makes it look like you are low on memory, but you are not! Everything is fine! If your application, or any other process needs more memory, Linux will automatically clear the cache and give memory for your application. Linux does this to speed up the system for you.

If, however, you find yourself needing to clear some RAM quickly to workaround another issue, like a VM misbehaving, you can force Linux to nondestructively drop caches using:

```
    echo 3 | sudo tee /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches
```